# How to fix a missing resgistered class?

Tags: java, android

I am using android studio and I want to include a library (MPPieChart). I've added the repository and the dependencies but when I tried to work it in the XML file, the android studio did not recognize it.

```
<com.github.mikephill.charting.charts.PieChart
    android:id="@+id/frmPieChart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout2"
</com.github.mikephill.charting.charts.PieChart>
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure you wrote it correctly? change please, com.github.mikephill.charting.charts.PieChart - >  com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart

Comment: yes, i sure. i cheeked it but i have the same problem

Comment: when I add library everything works for me and I saw the difference in package